# Running full node on OSX, how to tell if its working correctly?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, full-node

I'm running Bitcoin-QT 0.15.01 on an iMac (4 GHz Intel Core i7, 40GB RAM). It seems I am receiving the latest blocks, but is the rest working as it should?

I have opened port 8333 on my router and bitnodes is reporting that my node is accepting incoming connections.

Core reports 19 connections to the network but the log has a lot of errors like these:

```
09:20:08' progress=1.000000 cache=64.8MiB(478821txo)
2017-10-01 09:21:26 connect() to 65.130.52.89:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2017-10-01 09:21:36 receive version message: /Satoshi:0.14.1/: version 70015, blocks=487780, us=N.N.N.N:8333, peer=1634
2017-10-01 09:21:44 receive version message: /Snoopy:0.2.1/: version 70001, blocks=0, us=N.N.N.N:8333, peer=1635
2017-10-01 09:21:44 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2017-10-01 09:21:46 receive version message: /Satoshi:0.14.1/: version 70015, blocks=487780, us=N.N.N.N:8333, peer=1636
2017-10-01 09:22:28 receive version message: /bitnode.lee/: version 70015, blocks=487780, us=N.N.N.N:8333, peer=1637
2017-10-01 09:22:49 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000792640fb97fb9a8ed07ba99b37479a48ebbeff3b1c1044 height=487782 version=0x20000000 log2_work=87.201974 tx=258394764 date='2017-10-01 09:22:42' progress=1.000000 cache=64.8MiB(479294txo)
2017-10-01 09:23:27 ProcessMessages(version, 111 bytes) FAILED peer=1638
2017-10-01 09:23:37 receive version message: /bitnodes.21.co:0.1/: version 70015, blocks=487780, us=N.N.N.N:8333, peer=1639
2017-10-01 09:23:39 Pre-allocating up to position 0x7000000 in blk01013.dat
2017-10-01 09:23:39 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000a86b2c788d7d3acd3493b05b2e8a626d7a5aca20a3ecc1 height=487783 version=0x20000000 log2_work=87.202013 tx=258397039 date='2017-10-01 09:23:00' progress=1.000000 cache=65.1MiB(482014txo)
2017-10-01 09:23:51 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000004927be61b84dc22202b49e55e635ce746023436c1ed14d height=487784 version=0x20000000 log2_work=87.202051 tx=258397146 date='2017-10-01 09:23:51' progress=1.000000 cache=65.2MiB(482144txo)
2017-10-01 09:24:04 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2017-10-01 09:24:07 receive version message: /bitcoin-seeder:0.01/: version 60000, blocks=350000, us=N.N.N.N:8333, peer=1640
2017-10-01 09:24:18 receive version message: /bitcoinj:0.14.4/: version 70014, blocks=437811, us=127.0.0.1:8333, peer=1641
```

Comment: Thanks MCCCS, I couldn't figure why the carriage returns were not working or how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You can help the site by marking an answer as accepted if it is correct and addresses the question so that the question does not remain as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

Those are not errors/are benign errors. You have multiple connections and your node can be found on bitnodes. Your node is fine and working correctly.

Comment: Great, thank you Andrew! That puts my mind at rest.